# How do you the change Input Hidden Value?

Tags: c#, input, hidden, getelementbyid

I want to change the value of the input tag.  But it's not working at all.  I already found a working code that would change the value of the Select tag, but I haven't found a code that works well to change the value of the input tag below.

```
 <div id="phmiddle_0_CheckoutShippingInfo1_selectAddressDiv" name="selectAddressDiv">
   <select class="selecta" name="selAddressBook" id="selAddressBook">
     <option value="-1">Create a new address</option>
     <option value="{adbd6ae0-abf8-40ea-a18a-998afaeb37ad}">AAA AAA</option>
     <option value="{0e0e26a0-c490-476f-9a00-d3d76d7d69cd}">BBB BBB</option>
     <option value="{84496563-8dcb-42e6-b728-60646faf81d0}">CCC CCC</option>
   </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="idOfShiptoDefaultedToOrSelected"
     id="idOfShiptoDefaultedToOrSelected"
     value='{adbd6ae0-abf8-40ea-a18a-998afaeb37ad}' />
 </div>
```

This is the code I used to try to change the hidden input value.

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("idOfShiptoDefaultedToOrSelected").SetAttribute("value", "-1"); 
}
```

It wouldn't work at all. Am I missing something here like a select or click? I already tried them.

I also tried this one too

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("selAddressBook").SetAttribute("value", "-1");
```

^ THAT code can change the seladdressbook but it wouldn't change the input hidden value, which is `idOfShiptoDefaultedToOrSelected.`

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I'm using C# through a web control navigated at a HTTPS:// page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it in JavaScript:

```
$("#BUTTON_ID").click(function() {
$("idOfShiptoDefaultedToOrSelected").val("NEW_VALUE");
});
```

Comment: That's jQuery, not plain Javascript.